# Does Spring-Boot handle Kotlin coroutines apart from WebFlux context?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

We are trying to use Kotlin coroutines for asynchronous processing inside Spring-Boot backend.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to support it well (At least standard Spring MVC).

Basically, if we have a function that does asynchronous logic:

```
fun fetchUsersAsync(): Deferred<Users> {
    return GlobalScope.async {
            ...
    }
}
```

and this function is used with `await` at some point in service, which requires to put `suspend` annotation in a calling service function:

```
@Service
class MyService {
    suspend fun processUsers(): Users {
        return fetchUsersAsync().await()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible, and the only reference for suspend functionality in service was connected with WebFlux.

Has anyone faced the same situation? Thanks.

Comment: Your public functions in services and endpoints should not be suspendable. The code inside can easily be asynchronous. I don't know what was your main goal by defining 'processUsers()' suspend?

Comment: Thanks for response, @Neo! The main idea is a fact that await() call should be within a suspend function.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.4.0 and Spring 5.3 has provided support for Kotlin Coroutines in MVC servlet stack, so you can declare a suspend function without any issues. No need to use `runBlocking` and `await()` while using coroutines in servlet stack anymore. More information here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/languages.html#coroutines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call `await()` without declaring a `suspend` function, wrap it inside a coroutine builder, like this:

```
@Service
class MyService {
    fun processUsers(): Users {
        return runBlocking { fetchUsersAsync().await() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply: similar approach worked, thanks!

Comment: @Neo wouldn't it be better to use `suspend` and `coroutineScope()` instead of `runBlocking`?

Comment: @IrinaS. The answer clearly states: "call await() without declaring a suspend function"